# Only add "key/value" in new array if matching key exists in lookup data

Tags: php, arrays, lookup

I am restructuring an array by creating a new array.
The purpose with the new array is to flatten the code and also only
add the key-value-pairs that have the key in $array['lookup'].

**Question:**

How can I secure that the for-loop only create the key-value-pairs,
that are listed with key values in $array['lookup'] ?

```
<?php

// Data

$array = [

  'identification_posts' => [
    [
      "#COMPANY",
      "Ford"
    ],
    [
      "#SOFTWARE",
      "1.2"
    ],
    [
      "#id",
      "237"
    ],
  ],
  'lookup' => [
    '#COMPANY',
    '#SOFTWARE',
  ]

];

// Logics

print_r($array);

$newArray = [];

for ($i=0; $i < count($array['identification_posts']) ; $i++) {

  $newArray['identification_posts'][$array['identification_posts'][$i][0]] =
    $array['identification_posts'][$i][1];

}

print_r($newArray);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [identification_posts] => Array
        (
            [#COMPANY] => Ford
            [#SOFTWARE] => 1.2
            [#id] => 237
        )

)
```

**Wanted result**
(the key-value-pair [id] is not included due to it is missing in $array['lookup']

```
Array
(
    [identification_posts] => Array
        (
            [#COMPANY] => Ford
            [#SOFTWARE] => 1.2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, check if the value exists in the lookup array.  I have also changed the loop to use `foreach()` as it shortens a lot of the array lookups to make the code more readable (IMHO)...

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ( $array['identification_posts'] as $entry ){
    if ( in_array($entry[0],  $array['lookup']) !== false ) {
        $newArray['identification_posts'][$entry[0]] = $entry[1];
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Data

$array = [

    'identification_posts' => [
        [
            "#COMPANY",
            "Ford"
        ],
        [
            "#SOFTWARE",
            "1.2"
        ],
        [
            "#id",
            "237"
        ],
    ],
    'lookup' => [
        '#COMPANY',
        '#SOFTWARE',
    ]

];

// Logics
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

$lookup = array_flip($array['lookup']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['identification_posts']); $i++) {

    if (isset($lookup[$array['identification_posts'][$i][0]]))
        $newArray['identification_posts'][$array['identification_posts'][$i][0]] =
            $array['identification_posts'][$i][1];

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the index is `in_array`

```
$newArray = [];

$count = count($array['identification_posts']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $key = $array['identification_posts'][$i][0];
    $value = $array['identification_posts'][$i][1];

    if ( in_array($key, $array['lookup']) ){
        $newArray['identification_posts'][$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check the `value[0]` is in the `lookup`

```php
    $lookup = $array['lookup'];
    $newArray = ['identification_posts' => []];
    foreach ($array['identification_posts'] as $value) {
        if (in_array($value[0], $lookup)) {
            $newArray['identification_posts'][$value[0]] = $value[1];
        }
    }

    // var_dump($newArray);
```